# ContentFlow (coverflow) - How Can I Make it Work The Way I Want It?

Tags: javascript, css, coverflow

Im trying to use this plugin:

http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/

2 points:

1. I want to know how can I get it into my div and stay inside the volume of the div? As it is right now, my div is 185px, but when I put the coverflow inside of the div, it breaks out of it and plays outside the div.

   If I take the height off the div, it will stay inside the div, but... the div MUST remain at height of 185px. I dont really see any padding or margin elements inside the CoverFlow css, so im not sure what im supposed to edit.

   I also have plans to put the coverflow into an even smaller div on another page, so I want to know how to scale it and fit into my set-height div properly without problems.
2. When I load the page into another div thats in another page, the coverflow will not load. So basically, the coverflow only loads in its own page.  Ive put the links to the .js and css into the main file that loads the coverflow page, but its still not working.

Can anyone help me figure out these 2 important points?

Comment: Can you show us what have you done so far? a test page maybe? I've tested the plugin and you can change the container width `#ContentFlow` and the flow DIV will "shrink" to fit..as for the 2nd point the plugin support ajax calls!

Comment: i dont understand how to implement the ajax calls youre talking about. How would i do that in the simplest fashion possible, keeping in mind the plugin works fine when working in its own page currently?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening there is that ContentFlow completely ignores the container's height; it seems to be using some kind of fixed aspect, with only width being taken into consideration, and the height being calculated from that.

Therefore, the simplest solution, in your case, given that you have a fixed height, is to reduce the width of the container, therefore making ContentFlow calculate an smaller height.